# Magento 1.9.x in maintenance mode while having access to admin

Tags: admin, maintenance

I have successfully put magento 1.9.x in maintenance mode while still having access to admin area however I need to **access one more URL which is custom based module**. The following code worked fine to access admin area only.

```
$url=(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && strpos($url,'/admin') === false) {
    $basePath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/maintenance.php';
    exit;
}
```

How do I add another custom module in above code which has URI eg. www.domain.com/ModuleName/ and can be access directly while keeping the site in maintenance mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_exists($maintenanceFile) && strpos($url,'/ModuleName') === false && strpos($url,'/admin') === false
```

or simple base your logic on your IP and send everyone to maintenance mode:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'your_ip'){
     include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/maintenance.php';
     exit;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

using preg_match:

```
if(file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !preg_match('#/(admin|ModuleName)#',$url)){
      ...your code
}
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you! Just wondering if I could do this with an array?

Comment: you can do this with preg_match: !preg_match('#/(admin|ModuleName)#',$url)

Comment: preg_match  throwing up the error:- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in index.php on line 70

Comment: it means you have spare '{' on line 70. see my updated answer. just copy/paste in an appropriate place.

Comment: yes, you are right, and I actually missed one closing bracket ) before the closing braces. At last, preg_match is better way to achieve this. Many Thanks!